# Windows 10 machine rebooting intermittently

Tags: windows-10, power-supply, hardware-failure, crash, troubleshooting

My windows 10 machine is starting to frequently crash.  No BSOD, just power off and it starts back up.  There doesn't seem to be any pattern to it... I can be working the box gaming or something and it's fine.  And then it will crash 5 minutes after a restart.  Or it might crash in the middle of an intense game.

Reliability monitor shows all the crashes, but the only message is 'Windows was not properly shut down', and 'The previous system shutdown at  on  was unexpected'

I've looked at my CPU and GPU temps idle and under load and they seem quite okay.

Other thing I suspect is the PSU, but I don't know how to check it without buying equipment.  Anyone have any troubleshooting advice or tricks/software that can give me more data to figure out what the problem is?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2028504

Answer (score 0):

1.) Remove overclock.

2.) If step 1 does not work, try with a different PSU. You have to find a different PSU and try that out.

3.) If you conclude PSU is OK, conduct a MemTest. The memtest should run many times over, at least 3-4 hours. If there is no error in memtest as well, then test your system with a different mobo.